# How to use migrations in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, entity-framework, sequelize.js

I have used ORMS such as [EntityFramework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx), [Waterline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/waterline) and [Mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose). I just started using [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/). I have created a sample model. Later I wanted to add another column to the table corresponding to the same model. When I edit the model, the new field doesn't seem to be reflecting in the table unless I drop the table. Am I supposed to use Migrations? I got confused after reading the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/schema/#migrations-manual-schema-changes). Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use migrations as if you edit a model in sequelize when you application starts it will only create the table if it doesn't exist. It does not check if the schema is different thus it doesn't update the schema of your table.

If I were you, I would install `sequelize-cli` and then run the `sequelize init` command. This sets up your project ready to use migrations.

Please note that we using sequelize migrations you have to explicitly define the primary key, updatedAt and createdAt columns otherwise they will not great created!

The docs are not too bad about migrations: http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/migrations/

Comment: Adding primary key, updatedAt and createdAt columns explicitly is where I got stuck at. It works now